# Compiler error on windows but not on mac

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm running the same code on my laptop which is a mac and it **works fine**. (not using any specific mac-libraries). Now that i'm trying to send the code to my pc, i get ~300lines of errors.

CMD-OUTPUT:

```
C:\Users\joel\Desktop\Hej>g++ -std=c++11 dice.cpp
dice.cpp: In member function 'std::string dice::getOne()':
dice.cpp:28:19: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'st
d::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostrea
m_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}')
       return  one = cout << "------" << "\n!     !\n!  x  !\n!     !\n" << "---
---" << endl; //one
                   ^
dice.cpp:28:19: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string:52:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_cla
sses.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h
:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from dice.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<cha
r>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(const _CharT* __s)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'const char*'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Al
loc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(_CharT __c)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'char'
dice.cpp: In member function 'std::string dice::getTwo()':
dice.cpp:31:19: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'st
d::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostrea
m_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}')
       return  two = cout << "------" << "\n!    x!\n!     !\n!x    !\n" << "---
---" << endl; //two
                   ^
dice.cpp:31:19: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string:52:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_cla
sses.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h
:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from dice.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<cha
r>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(const _CharT* __s)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'const char*'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Al
loc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(_CharT __c)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'char'
dice.cpp: In member function 'std::string dice::getThree()':
dice.cpp:34:21: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'st
d::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostrea
m_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}')
       return  three =  cout << "------" << "\n!x    !\n!  x  !\n!    x!\n" << "
------" << endl; //three
                     ^
dice.cpp:34:21: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string:52:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_cla
sses.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h
:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from dice.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<cha
r>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(const _CharT* __s)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'const char*'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Al
loc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(_CharT __c)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'char'
dice.cpp: In member function 'std::string dice::getFour()':
dice.cpp:37:20: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'st
d::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostrea
m_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}')
       return  four =  cout << "------" << "\n! x x !\n!     !\n! x x !\n" << "-
-----" << endl; //four
                    ^
dice.cpp:37:20: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string:52:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_cla
sses.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h
:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from dice.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<cha
r>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(const _CharT* __s)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'const char*'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Al
loc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(_CharT __c)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'char'
dice.cpp: In member function 'std::string dice::getFive()':
dice.cpp:40:20: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'st
d::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostrea
m_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}')
       return  five = cout << "------" << "\n! x x !\n!  x  !\n! x x !\n" << "--
----" << endl; //five
                    ^
dice.cpp:40:20: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string:52:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_cla
sses.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h
:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from dice.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<cha
r>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(const _CharT* __s)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'const char*'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Al
loc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(_CharT __c)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'char'
dice.cpp: In member function 'std::string dice::getSix()':
dice.cpp:43:18: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'st
d::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostrea
m_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}')
       return six =  cout << "------" << "\n! x x !\n! x x !\n! x x !\n" << "---
---" << endl; //six
                  ^
dice.cpp:43:18: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\string:52:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\locale_cla
sses.h:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h
:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from dice.cpp:3:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<cha
r>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(const _CharT* __s)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:554:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'const char*'
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note: std:
:basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allo
c>::operator=(_CharT) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Al
loc = std::allocator<char>] <near match>
       operator=(_CharT __c)
       ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:565:7: note:   no
 known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type
{aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' to 'char'
dice.cpp: In function 'int main()':
dice.cpp:63:20: error: 'numeric_limits' is not a member of 'std'
     if (cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')){
                    ^
dice.cpp:63:50: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
     if (cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')){
                                                  ^
dice.cpp:63:57: error: no matching function for call to 'max()'
     if (cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')){
                                                         ^
dice.cpp:63:57: note: candidates are:
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\vector:60:0,
                 from dice.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:216:5: note: temp
late<class _Tp> const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&)
     max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:216:5: note:   te
mplate argument deduction/substitution failed:
dice.cpp:63:57: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
     if (cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')){
                                                         ^
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\vector:60:0,
                 from dice.cpp:2:
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:260:5: note: temp
late<class _Tp, class _Compare> const _Tp& std::max(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Com
pare)
     max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
     ^
c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.8.1\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:260:5: note:   te
mplate argument deduction/substitution failed:
dice.cpp:63:57: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided
     if (cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')){
                                                         ^
```

File:

```
    //dice
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class dice{
  private:
    string one;
    string two;
    string three;
    string four;
    string five;
    string six;
  public:
    dice(){srand(time(NULL));};
    dice(string one, string two, string three, string four, string five, string six){
      this->one=one;
      this->two=two;
      this->three=three;
      this->four=four;
      this->five=five;
      this->six=six;
    }
    string getOne(){
      return  one = cout << "------" << "\n!     !\n!  x  !\n!     !\n" << "------" << endl; //one
    }
    string getTwo(){
      return  two = cout << "------" << "\n!    x!\n!     !\n!x    !\n" << "------" << endl; //two
    }
    string getThree(){
      return  three =  cout << "------" << "\n!x    !\n!  x  !\n!    x!\n" << "------" << endl; //three
    }
    string getFour(){
      return  four =  cout << "------" << "\n! x x !\n!     !\n! x x !\n" << "------" << endl; //four
    }
    string getFive(){
      return  five = cout << "------" << "\n! x x !\n!  x  !\n! x x !\n" << "------" << endl; //five
    }
    string getSix(){
      return six =  cout << "------" << "\n! x x !\n! x x !\n! x x !\n" << "------" << endl; //six
    }
};



int main(){ //main

  dice myDice = dice(); //referens
  string c, stop="stop";


  while(1){
    cout << "Generate two random dice: press [ENTER]\n";

    //random funktion nedan

    string c;


    if (cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')){

      for(int i=0;i<2;i++){ //select two random numbers
        int num;

        int min=1,max=6;
        num = (rand() % max + min);
        //if
        if      (num==1){
          myDice.getOne();
        }else if(num==2){
          myDice.getTwo();
        }else if(num==3){
          myDice.getThree();
        }else if(num==4){
          myDice.getFour();
        }else if(num==5){
          myDice.getFive();
        }else if(num==6){
          myDice.getSix();
        }else{
          cout << "higher than 6 or lower than 1. If that happens, i'm quitting programming (may this function never be used)\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }
    return 0;
}
```

What's causing this? I'm using g++ to compile on windows. Can someone please try to run this code on windows and confirm that it's indeed windows-related?

Comment: I am not sure why the error occurs (or why it works on mac) in general but your `return ... = cout << ...` is most likely not what you want to do. `cout` prints on the command line. There is nothing to return. Also do you have the same gcc-version / compiler flags on both systems?

Comment: Updating `gcc` version should solve your problem.

Comment: `std::cout << X;` returns a `std::ostream&`. This is not convertible to a string.

Comment: @Hayt I tried removing "return" but it didn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: @Shavran40 i'm using the latest version? Edit: I've updated to the latest, same error.

Comment: what is the latest? `gcc --version` should help. You should also change the signature to return `void` not string. Then it should work without return. I assume your OS-X gcc may be older than the windows one and not reporting this error.

Comment: @hayt (i've just updated to the latest version of gcc 5.3.0-2). don't really follow you here. what do you mean by changing my signature?

Comment: I really wonder what compiler (name and version) do you use on your mac?

Comment: `void getOne() { cout <<  ...  ;}` It depends if you want to print in getOne() or just assign in the function.

Comment: @hayt didn't solve the problem, thanks anyway tho.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this random `out = cout << ...` stuff? Where did you read that you should do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a mac, and compiling on said mac yields:

```
/Users/rhodges/play/print/print/main.cpp:28:21: error: no viable overloaded '='
        return  one = cout << "------" << "\n!     !\n!  x  !\n!     !\n" << "------" << endl; //one
                ~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /Users/rhodges/play/print/print/main.cpp:3:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1376:19: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::basic_ostream<char>' to 'const std::__1::basic_string<char>' for 1st argument
    basic_string& operator=(const basic_string& __str);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1379:19: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::basic_ostream<char>' to 'std::__1::basic_string<char>' for 1st argument
    basic_string& operator=(basic_string&& __str)
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1383:45: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::basic_ostream<char>' to 'const value_type *' (aka 'const char *') for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY basic_string& operator=(const value_type* __s) {return assign(__s);}
                                            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1384:19: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::basic_ostream<char>' to 'value_type' (aka 'char') for 1st argument
    basic_string& operator=(value_type __c);
                  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:1387:19: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::__1::basic_ostream<char>' to 'initializer_list<value_type>' (aka 'initializer_list<char>') for 1st argument
    basic_string& operator=(initializer_list<value_type> __il) {return assign(__il.begin(), __il.size());}
```

six times over

this is invalid:

```
 string getOne(){
      return  one = cout << "------" << "\n!     !\n!  x  !\n!     !\n" << "------" << endl; //one
    }
```

`std::cout << XXX` returns a `std::ostream&`, not a `std::string`.

what will work is:

```
string getOne(){
  if (one.empty())
  {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << "------" << "\n!     !\n!  x  !\n!     !\n" << "------" << endl; //one
    one = ss.str();
  }
  return one;
}
```

You'll need to `#include <sstream>`

It might actually be easier to implement it this way (fewer moving parts):

```
//dice
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

class dice{
private:
    static const char* const one;
    static const char* const two;
    static const char* const three;
    static const char* const four;
    static const char* const five;
    static const char* const six;
    static const char* const texts_[6];
public:
    dice(){
        srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    };

    std::ostream& show(std::ostream& os, int value) const
    {
        if (value < 1 || value > 6)
            return os << "invalid value\n";
        return os << texts_[value - 1];
    }
};

const char* const dice::one =
"------\n"
"!     !\n"
"!  x  !\n"
"!     !\n"
"------\n";

const char* const dice::two =
"------\n"
"!x    !\n"
"!     !\n"
"!    x!\n"
"------\n";

const char* const dice::three =
"------\n"
"!x    !\n"
"!  x  !\n"
"!    x!\n"
"------\n";

const char* const dice::four =
"------\n"
"! x x !\n"
"!     !\n"
"! x x !\n"
"------\n";

const char* const dice::five =
"------\n"
"! x x !\n"
"!  x  !\n"
"! x x !\n"
"------\n";

const char* const dice::six =
"------\n"
"! x x !\n"
"! x x !\n"
"! x x !\n"
"------\n";

const char* const dice::texts_[6] {
    one, two, three, four, five, six
};


int main(){ //main

    dice myDice = dice(); //referens
    string c, stop="stop";


    while(1){
        cout << "Generate two random dice: press [ENTER]\n";

        //random funktion nedan

        string c;


        if (cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n')){

            for(int i=0;i<2;i++){ //select two random numbers
                int num;

                int min=1,max=6;
                num = (rand() % max + min);
                myDice.show(std::cout, num);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's so weird. it works on my mac running Mavericks...Why would i have to use this? Doesn't make any sense? I'm just printing out signs onto the console.

Comment: I'm not using xcode. I'm just using a random text-editor and compiling within the terminal.

Comment: g++ --version? What do you get if you type this?

Comment: 4.2.1 clang-700.1.81, still don't understand what i've done wrong and why it should cause this many errors :S

Comment: @Joel: If you were just printing to the console, that would look like `cout << "something";`, not `return one = cout << "something";`. The latter makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @Joel - what the code does wrong is `std::string two = std::cout << whatever;`. That's meaningless and, as @richardhodges says, you should separate formatting the text string from assigning it to the object that's eventually going to hold it.

Comment: yeah i saw that, i think i just forgot to remove my previous solution that was in place there. (was saving the cout in a different variable instead of calling it out straight away like: one = cout. but yeah. I've removed return and it still gives me errors

Comment: @Joel: And the `one =`?

Comment: @PeteBecker so, eg. like this: `one = cout << xxx; getOne(){return one; }` ?

Comment: @Joel - no, for the reason I just gave: that code makes no sense. **Read** the answer that Richard Hodges gave you. It has code that will work.